# AWS Cloudformation Template: Which Section?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

If I have written a cloudFormation template that created one EC2 instance and I need to install packages and make some configuration changes when the machine is started up. Which section of the template should I edit in order to achieve this?

Would it be Properties, Parameters, Outputs or Mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install software by putting a script in `UserData` under `Properties`.  The script will be run after the server is deployed

Here's an example installing Apache:

```
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "\n",
          [
            "#!/bin/bash -xe",
            "sudo yum update -y",
            "sudo yum install httpd -y",
            "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start",
            "echo \"<html><body>Installed httpd successfully\" > /var/www/html/index.html",
            "echo \"</body></html>\" >> /var/www/html/index.html"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

There's a lot more you can do with `Metadata`.  Check the reference out for more details

**References**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html

Answer (score 0):

In **UserData** you have to mention all the bash scripts using which you like to install packages

so your Cloudformation would looks like

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
   "Parameters" : {some paramters...}
   "Mappings" : {some mappings...}
   "Resources" : {
      "EC2Instance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance", 
        "Properties" : {
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "UserData" : {here you have to add all your script to deploy while boot up Ec2 }
   }
}
```